# Heroku discord bot hosting Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: heroku, discord, discord.js, hosting

So this is my first time trying to run a discord bot via Heroku instead of local, but there's an error that keeps occuring (I've read similar topics but still couldn't fix it), what did I do wrong?

My main code;

```js
const discord = require('discord.js')
const mongo = require('./mongo')
const noblox = require('noblox.js')

const client = new discord.Client()


const config = require('./config.json')
const welcome = require('./welcome')
const verify = require('./verify')





client.on('ready', async () => {
    console.log('The bot is ready!')

    welcome(client)
    verify(client)

})

client.login(config.token)
```

In another topic I also saw someone had issues with mongoDB connection, but I have the ip requirement set to 0.0.0.0/0, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Let me know if you see what I did wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this, I had to go to recourses tab in heroku, turn off npm start, and turn on the functionality of my Procfile.

Comment: So you defined in a Procfile the start command and deleted the default created by a node project?

I don't quite understand what you mean by turn off npm start, can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @VioPage worked for me and I wanted to clarify what you should do, because it wasn't so obvious immediately for me.

I fixed this same issue by going to the resources tab and then turning on my "worker" process I defined in my Procfile. As long as the process you define in your Procfile it should work and not cause this error